# Cannot access Box API file contents (Oauth2)

Tags: php, curl, box-api

I couldn't able to access the Box file contents using PHP-CURL. I have tried accessing XML and JSON files, but I'm not getting any results. I have tried the following code:

```
$url = 'https://api.box.com/2.0/files/File_id/content';

$header = array('Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
echo $returndata = curl_exec($curl);
```

Please help me to find a solution for this.

Comment: @Jack: Is this a library?

Comment: @Jack: Yeah I'm using CURL. I'm not familiar with the code you provided. Can you provide me some more information about this CURLOPT_CAINFO ?

Comment: Just `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);`, run it again and then search for the error that's shown.

Comment: @Jack: I have added the above code, but still it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked fine when added the following code:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Hope it will help someone facing the same issue.